# Custom cursor in java

Tags: java, swing

Recently I'm building a java swing application and want to add a custom cursor. I used the following code,

```
public void customCursor() {
    Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    Image image = toolkit.getImage("pencil.gif");
    Point hotspot = new Point(0,0);
    Cursor cursor = toolkit.createCustomCursor(image, hotspot, "pencil");
    setCursor(cursor);
}
```

And call the customCursor() method inside constructor. When i run the application my cursor is invisible. I tried giving the absolute path and using a url also. Still the same problem. Also I got to know (as mentioned here http://en.allexperts.com/q/Java-1046/cursor-1.htm) that the best cursor size for windows OS is 32x32. So for the above code set i added the following line,

```
toolkit.getBestCursorSize(32, 32);
```

still no progress. Also i tried using a 32x32 pixel image, still bad luck. Can anybody suggest a solution. (in case of a version issue, i'm using jdk 1.7 and jre7)

Comment: I should mention, if you use an image larger then 32x32, Windows will typically truncate the everything beyond 32x32 pixel range, so, it might be possible that you're just seeing white space.  Make sure that the image it self is exactly 32x32

Comment: @Makoto I would argue that, apart from the "accepted" answer is link to an offsite resource, this isn't so much about how to create a custom cursor, as the OP has already shown working code, but why there particular image doesn't work, which sounds more like an issue with the location of the image or the means by which it is been loaded and/or the size of the image under Windows - IMHO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The likely cause is going to be the location of the image.

From you code example, the image "seems" to be an embedded resource.  These resources can't be accessed like normal files on the file system.

Instead of

```
 Image image = toolkit.getImage("pencil.gif");
```

Try using...

```
 Image image = toolkit.getImage(getClass().getResource("pencil.gif"));
```

assuming the image resides within the same location as the class file or

```
 Image image = toolkit.getImage(getClass().getResource("/pencil.gif"));
```

if the image resides somewhere else (this example demonstrates the image located in the default package).

[image: Cursors]

Comment: This method works. Also the image I first used is too large. I tried using a 32x32 image and now it works perfectly. Thank you.