# Catch WM_SETCURSOR in Swing

Tags: java, swing, winapi, jna

I need to do the next cpp code in my Swing application:

```
const HCURSOR customCursor = (HCURSOR)LoadImage(NULL, "filepath/some.cur", IMAGE_CURSOR, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
SetCursor(customCursor);
```

I supposed that I can do it via JNA. But I couldn't do that, and I guess that Swing overrides my changes.
And now I want to catch `WM_SETCURSOR` from Swing and then do `SetCursor` with JNA.

So my answer is next:
How can I catch/override `WM_SETCURSOR` in Swing application?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24818948/custom-cursor-in-java I suspect there isn't a way to "catch WM_SETCURSOR" in Swing, particularly if you aren't running it on Windows ;)

Comment: @KevinBoone I will run my app only on Windows, and I need to "catch WM_SETCURSOR" for setting big custom cursor because Swing can't set cursor bigger than 32x32

Comment: My point is that Swing tries to be platform-neutral. Very little of the underlying platform UI is exposed. Even if you could somehow tap the Windows event handler -- which will be buried deep in the Swing framework -- you've still got to fight swing to prevent your UI changes being reversed. I'm not saying it's impossible, only that there's unlikely to be any simple solution.